# Eclipse Kepler configuring c++ 11

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11

I'm trying to configure eclipise kepler to use c++ 11.

I appended `-std=c++11` to:

```
Properties > c/c++ build > settings > GCC c++ complier > Miscellaneous>other flags
```

But when I compile the project it says:

> compilation terminated. /bin/sh: 1: -std=c++11: not found

I'm using gcc on ubuntu,

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flags (or compiler options) are nothing but ordinary command line arguments passed to the compiler executable.

Assuming you are invoking g++ from the command line (terminal):

```
$ g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 your_file.cpp -o your_program
```

or

```
$ g++ -Wall -g -std=c++0x your_file.cpp -o your_program
```

if the above doesn't work.

So in your case if -std=c++11 does not work, try -std=c++0x

Another source for this error could be an old compiler version.

Type `gcc --version` into the terminal and check the version. Here is a quick overview which version is capable of c++11:

> C++11 Support in GCC
>
> GCC 4.8.1 was the first feature-complete implementation of the 2011
>   C++ standard, previously known as C++0x.
>
> This mode can be selected with the -std=c++11 command-line flag, or
>   -std=gnu++11 to enable GNU extensions as well.

Link: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html